# Differentiate tap on RightCalloutAccessoryView and CalloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: ios, iphone, maps

I've implemented apple maps in my app and now I want to call different methods when tapping on rightCalloutAccessoryView and on the rest of the annotation. Is it possible to differentiate between these two? If it is please provide a solution or share your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sold this. For anyone that will struggle with this in future, you should add custom TapGestureRecognizer to the details button, so the OS can differentiate between the two events, otherwise wouldn't.